# Flatten product image directory structure

Tags: catalog, image

I need to replace all images in the product catalogue with larger images. The filenames are the same but Magento spread all images under some very nested directory structure like

example.com/media/catalog/product/d/c/product-image.jpg

Is there a way to tell Magento to flatten this directory stucture to one directory so that I can just bulk update all the images via FTP without having to work my way through the Magento admin one by one?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to flatten the directory structure

Take a look at [How to upload product images via FTP instead of using the Magento UI?](http://web-design.sayyor.com/2012/10/24/how-to-upload-product-images-via-ftp-instead-of-using-the-magento-ui/)

> The structure is fairly simple.  For product ABC1234, the images for
>   that product would be placed in the
>
> media/catalog/product/a/b/abc1234.jpg
>   media/catalog/product/a/b/abc1234_t.jpg (etc).
>
> The first folder in the product folder is the first character of the
>   product number. The subfolder under that is the second character of
>   the product number.
>
> So for product DEF6789, the structure would be:
>
> /media/catalog/product/d/e/def6789.jpg

Assuming that there is some logic to your file and they have the same name as the existing image in magento then you could either

1. Create a bash script to move them to the correct directory (assuming that the image name is also the product name)
2. Create a script that load your product collection the programmatically update the product see [Magento programmatically add product image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456954/magento-programmatically-add-product-image)

**Be careful to make backups of your directory structure before running these scripts, as you can severely mess up your files if you are not knowledgeable and careful.**

Answer (score 0):

Use Magmi to do this. It will likely be faster and easier

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

- You can set it to update existing products and give it the new images in a CSV format, which you can generate in Excel or a different spreadsheet program.